# Creating a variable in layout file and using it in all view files

Tags: php, yii2

I have created a new variable in `views/layouts/main.php` file, which is

```
$user = User::findOne(Yii::$app->user->id);
```

When i access this variable in `views/site/index.php` file, Yii2 through an error with `undefined variable $user`,

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general answer to this question is to use a Base Class for the Controller and set a variable in that controller.

**No set members in layout view!**

For example:

```
class BaseController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
    public $sharedMember;

    public function init()
    {
         parent::init();

         $this->sharedMember = 10;
    }
}
```

For all other controllers:

```
class ControllerA extends BaseController
{
      public function actionIndex()
      {
            return $this->render('index');
      }
}
```

In the index action of the ControllerA

```
echo $this->context->sharedMember;
```

that will display `10`.

Answer (score 1):

use as

> global $user;

here you are calling the variable globally.

Comment: So i can use this variable in all view files right?

Comment: yes, wherever you require the variable to be utilized, you can call it globally.

Comment: Using global variables in this case is a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

For your problem, you don't have to set or pass any variables. Use `Yii::$app->user->identity`, it already contails model of current logged user.

I'd recommend to create separate method in `User` model:

```
/**
 * Get current user
 * @return User
 */ 
public static function getCurrent()
{
    return Yii::$app->user->identity;
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
<div><?= User::getCurrent()->name ?></div>
```

Not only it's a bit shorter and more readable, it provides full autocomplete and highlighting of available properties and methods when using IDE.

Answer (score 0):

in your class user, create a new property called protected $id;, then create a setter method and from your views/layouts/main.php call the setter with the variable in it.

```
class user{
protected $id;
}
public class set_id($id){
$this-id = $id;
}


main.php:
$user->set_id($your_variable);
```

now from index.php you just access it, you know how